# JSON to NSMutableArray with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, afnetworking

I have a webpage with the code in JSON:

```
[
    {"url":"event.com","name":"Event name","event":"Event"},
    {"url":"event.com","name":"Event name 2","event":"Event"},
    {"url":"event.com","name":"Event name 3","event":"Event 3sw"}
]
```

I need this data to be stored in an `NSMutableArray`, like this, with a loop:

```
[eventsArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url,name,event, nil]];
[eventsArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url,name,event, nil]];
[eventsArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url,name,event, nil]];
```

How It's possible, maybe with AFNetworking?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252100/parsing-json-string-to-a-nsmutablearray

Answer (score 1):

There are many different JSON Parsers. Apple provides one called `NSJSONSerialization`

Check here for a very similar question:

[How to use NSJSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization)

Or the docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That doesn't answer his question.  He wants the data in Foundation objects structured differently than the JSON.

Comment: How I can do it using AFNetworking library ?

Comment: looks like they have it built in. Follow the examples here:http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html Here is an example of them getting a json object https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking#download-and-parse-json

Answer (score 0):

While you can of course create your own JSON parser, I don't think it would be a good idea. Here is a github repository for an Objective-C JSON parser

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Read the documentation and you should be good to go